# PHP array_combine & range VS foreach loop to get array of numbers

Tags: php

I have been thinking about this, for code readability I tend to use php built in functions like `range` & `array_combine` to generate an array of numbers like this:

```
array(
   5 => 5,
   10 => 10,
   15 => 15,
   20 => 20,
   25 => 25,
   ...
   60 => 60
);
```

So currently I use this to generate above:

```
$nums = range(5, 60, 5);
$nums = array_combine($nums, $nums);
```

I was wondering if there is a speed or memory difference between above approach and simply using loop like this:

```
for ($i = 5; $i <= 60; $i++) {
   $nums[$i] = $i;

   $i += 5;
}
```

I just want to know if my approach is good practice or if someone who would look at my code would try to find out where I live?

Comment: This question is best suited for [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com). Also, performance testing is done by simply taking a timestamp before and after function execution then comparing the time between the two. Do go ahead and try this and let us know if you can't figure it out.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy will do testing. I still want to know in terms of approach if its the right approach or not or it simply depends on one's perspective

Comment: `range` still uses a `for loop` to achieve this, it's simply a wrapper for it is all.

Comment: you'd have to benchmark it, but I suspect the for() loop would be more efficient, since you're only using/building one array. the range/combine option will effectively be producing 2.

Comment: ...however, I find the `range` and combine approach *easier to understand*, since those functions only have one specific purpose. A loop could do any number of things, and you need to actually read and understand the logic within it. And I doubt either is significantly faster, so readability wins here IMO.

Comment: So, what do you need this for? You could take an OOP approach which would be faster still, but it wouldn't use arrays.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following method seems to be fast for small numbers:

```
$tmp = range(5,$limit,5);
$tmp = array_combine($tmp, $tmp);
```

However, the for loop is much faster for bigger numbers:

```
for($i =5; $i<=$limit; $i += 5)
    $tmp[$i] = $i;
```

Try the following code [here](http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php):

```
 <?php
$limit = 200;

$time_start = microtime(true);
$tmp = range(5,$limit,5);
$tmp = array_combine($tmp, $tmp);
$time_end = microtime(true);
echo  $time_end - $time_start;
echo "<br/>";
//print_r($tmp);
echo "<br/>";


$time_start = microtime(true);
$tmp = array();
for($i =5; $i<=$limit; $i += 5)
    $tmp[$i] = $i;
$time_end = microtime(true);
echo  $time_end - $time_start;
echo "<br/>";
//print_r($tmp);
```

for `$limit = 200` the first method is faster:

```
1=> 2.0980834960938E-5
2=> 2.1934509277344E-5
```

**range & combination wins!**

for `$limit = 500` the second method is faster:

```
1=> 3.7908554077148E-5
2=> 2.9087066650391E-5
```

**for loop wins!**

So in my opinion, I would pick the second method (for loop) since for small number, even if the first method is faster, the time difference is negligible. However, for large numbers, the second method is always faster, and that what we care about in computer science, the **worst time**

**Conclusion:**

For loop is the winner!

Comment: Thank you for taking the time & explaining.